# Count the number of items with a condition in MongoDB collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong with my query. I want to get the number of "alertes" with the field "resolved: false" so my query is :

```
Alertes.find({resolved: false}).count();
```

But it returns me 0 despite I have 1 entry in the collection with the field resolved: false

Somone could help me to figure out what I'm doing wrong ?

[image]

Comment: can you post a sample document from your "Alertes" collections?

Comment: the syntax is correct, by any chance are you storing 'false' as string instead of false as boolean? in that case query will not work.

Comment: So felix look the edit, chridam I'm doing it in Javascript I'll try the async method RESULT: `Alertes.count is not a function`, then RahulKumar I'm storing it as boolean

Comment: Even if I do `Alertes.find({}).count();` I got 0 ...

Comment: did you save your data into that collection?

Comment: I founded the problem ! I'm using IronRouter and I had forgot to subscribe in Iron router, I post the solution

Comment: Then I guess the problem comes from your Alertes variable. It may not point on the right collection... How do you instanciate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had forgot to subscribe to the collection in my IronRouter file :

```
Router.route('/', {
  name: 'home',
  waitOn: function() {
    return [
      Meteor.subscribe('infosContainers'),
      Meteor.subscribe('infosMachines'),
      Meteor.subscribe('alertes'),
    ];
  },
  fastRender: true,
});
```

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
Alertes.find({resolved: false}).fecth().length
```

If you are running this code at the client side, make sure you have subscribed to this collection, and that you have documents that satisfy the filter you are looking for.
Try to query all documents (with no filter) to make sure the documents are there with the query above, and check what you get back:

```
Alertes.find().fecth()
```

If you don't find any documents with the resolved property set to false, then the query is returning correctly, and the problem is your subscription.